# stringwithcontentsofurl file deprecated in ios 2.0 warning IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Hi in my application I'm showing the route map using google map in that its showing warning like .

> stringwithcontentsofurl  file deprecated in ios 2.0

The code which I'm using.

```
   -(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {

        NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
        NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];

        NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
        NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
        NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);

        NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl];
        NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

        return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
       }
```

In the above code in a particular line.

> NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl];

This above line its showing warning like that please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there is anything that you don't understand about the documentation. Start Xcode, Command-Shift-0, type in "stringWithContentsOfURL" into the search field, and it tells you right there what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was depreciated.You can use it as below

```
 NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: i have already changed if i change its showing like incompatible pointer types sending NSURL to parameter of type NSString

Comment: I modified the code check it..!I have Replaced file with URL in above code

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using is deprecated. Use `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding: error:]`.

Comment: i have already changed if i change its showing like incompatible pointer types sending NSURL to parameter of type NSString

Comment: with this your mentions error that paramiter parsing issue check properly.